CSS Positioning - Content overlapping Image
Here is the HTML and CSS below. The content keeps overlapping image. The end goal is to have it responsive. It use to work, but all the sudden I cannot get it to resolve. Used AI, used online resources I just cannot seem to get it fixed. I can post entire code if it helps. These are just the specific sections that seem to be effected.
<section id="bio">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="bio-box">
                <div class="bio-image">
                    <img src="img/jacob-kern.jpg" alt="Jacob Kern">
                </div>
                <div class="bio-content">
                    <h3>Jacob Kern</h3>
                    <h3>CEO | Founder</h3>
                    <h3>RZR Solutions</h3>
                    <h3>Faith Based Leadership</h3>
                    <blockquote>
                        <strong>"At RZR Solutions, our values are deeply rooted in our faith. As a veteran, we are always committed to doing the right thing, guided by integrity and a strong ethical foundation. This dedication ensures we provide honest, reliable, and trustworthy services to our clients."</strong>
                    </blockquote>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

Here is the CSS
/* Bio section styling */
#bio .container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap; /* Allow wrapping on smaller screens */
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bio-box {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f9f9f9; /* Match the background color of feature boxes */
    padding: 20px; /* Add padding to match feature boxes */
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); /* Add shadow to match feature boxes */
    margin: 50px 0;
    border-left: 5px solid var(--secondary-color); /* Full-length border */
    flex-wrap: wrap; /* Allow wrapping on smaller screens */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bio-image {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.bio-content {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 20px;
    border-left: 3px solid var(--primary-color);
    color: #555;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    word-break: break-word;
}

.bio-content h3 {
    margin: 0;
    color: var(--dark-font-color);
}

.bio-content blockquote {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #555;
}



You have the image set to a fixed width. It can't be responsive with fixed values.

That resolved it, I have been staring at this for 3 days. Thank you.

You're hoping for the image contained inside of .bio-image to be of the right size. You should define the img's size, like so:
.bio-image img{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}

https://jsfiddle.net/uof1tp6d/
